Short story where a scientist develops a virus that renders everyone on Earth sterile
I read this story as part of a book of science fiction short stories back in the eighties.
A scientist develops a virus that renders people sterile and spreads it through sexual contact. Within a few short years everyone on Earth is sterile, there are no births. Then after a few years, he develops a vaccine that renders people fertile again, and it is distributed for free, but the result is, no unwanted pregnancies, only wanted children are born.
I can't remember for the life of me who wrote it or what the title was. I went back to the Berkley library to look for it again and could not find it.

It isn't as good a fit as the existing answers, but just possibly How We Saved the Human Race by David Gerrold as discussed in the question Short story: Scientist creates virus that causes near-sterility, first villainized then later treated as hero.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Too many differences to be the answer, but there are some similarities in a movie titled "Kiss the girls and make them die."

This may be the 1983 Theodore Sturgeon story "Not an Affair." It contains the elements of worldwide sterility caused by a virus, and then a later reversal which can only be effected by women.
The virus causes the affected woman to be become pregnant after her next sexual encounter, then miscarry, then become sterile.
The reversal consists of having to eat a bland substance exclusive of all other foods "even salt" for several months, which also produces undesirable effects like having the user's hair fall out.
Having to endure this regimen is supposed to ensure that there won't be any unwanted children, and the story ends with a statement to this effect.
It is strongly implied (to the point of certainty) that the virus ("viroid" in the story) was created by one of the characters (a genetics researcher). The spread of the disease was started by his students using a powerful sex pheromone to seduce random women.
IMHO, this is one of Sturgeon's weaker efforts.

Thanks, sounds likely. I'd have to find it and read it.

@LZB You can read it at the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v065n04_1983-10/page/n91/mode/2up Is that the story you remember?

Not the story I remember but the message is the same. I downloaded  it. The plus is there's a story by Fritz Leiber in there too.

@LZB thanks for the feedback! I hope you find your story, it must be amazingly similar. Please let us know if you do.

Seventy Years of Decpop by Philip Jose' Farmer, might be the answer, allowing for some misremembering- the sterilization is via an aerosol spray, distributed around the world, and the population recovers through a high birth rate of the few who can have children at all.
From this site:

A dark and gloomy tale of a future Earth, where the population is
decimated by sterilization. Forced sterilization, by one individual
who invented an aerosol that had been spread all over the world. Only
a few of the people stayed fertile. What happens with society if there
are only a few babies born?

It's available here

That is what I remember
